# Need help on a T-SQL XPath query

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath

I'm hoping somebody can help me solve a syntax problem with a TSQL xpath query.

Given the following xml:

```
<emails>
    <email></email>
    <email></email>
</emails>
```

I'm trying to execute the following query:

```
select * from messages where SendTo.value('(/emails/email)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%[email value]%'
```

My query looks only in the first email element and it needs to look in all email elements.

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Your xml looks incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
select * from messages
CROSS APPLY SendTo.nodes('/emails/email') AS Artists(a)
where a.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') like '%[email value]%'
```

Demo in [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63448/1)

Comment: It works in SQL Fiddle but not in my query analyzer. I solved it using the following query:

SELECT messageid,[sendto] from dbo.messages
where [sendto].exist('/emails/email[.="email@hotmail.com"]') = 1

Comment: @user135498 If you want to use `exist` and wildcards you should have a look at contains. `SendTo.exist('/emails/email[contains(text()[1], "abc")]') = 1`. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d5cd4/1)